# Canceling a Mega account

Tags: account-management, mega

I just made an account on [Mega](https://mega.co.nz/) that I want to cancel, but I can’t find any option for doing this. So, how do you cancel a Mega account?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From their [terms of service](https://mega.co.nz/#terms):

> Suspension and Termination
>
> 21) You can terminate your access to the website and our services at any time by sending an email to support@mega.co.nz requesting termination. However, we will not provide any part- refund for any time not used on any subscription you may have.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more detailed answer, from the MEGA-support:

> To cancel your actual MEGA account: Can you please log into your MEGA
>   account and remove its contents (any files or folders) to Rubbish Bin.
>   Then click on Rubbish bin and ‘Clear Rubbish Bin’ as well.
>
> When you emptied your MEGA account please advise us emailing from the
>   email address your account is associated with.
>
> We will get your MEGA account cancelled from the system and release
>   your email address. We will advise you when this is completed.
>
> If you have a PRO account and want to cancel your payment agreement
>   with Mega Ltd., log into your PayPal account, go to your 'Profile' and
>   click 'My Money'. Then update your agreement in your 'My pre-approved
>   payments' section as you wish. You may file a PayPal dispute and apply
>   for a refund.
>
> We are making changes to improve usability and address technical
>   issues following our recent re-launch out of Beta. We apologize for
>   any inconvenience caused and have a MEGA-awesome day!